# InDesign text boxes always come in 5 columns

Tags: adobe-indesign

I am having trouble with InDesign (v.CS6) text boxes always defaulting to 5 columns. I changed Margins and Columns one column, but this doesn't work. And when I manually change a box to 1 column and add to the library, when I use the library item it goes back to 5 columns. Help!
Thanks!!
Liz

Comment: Do your text boxes have an object style applied to them? If so, the five columns are likely set in the style; adding the frame to your library presumably just removes manual overrides from the version stored in the library.

Answer (score 3):

In InDesign **with no file open**, choose `Object > Text Frame Options...` and set it to what you want.

By doing this *with no file open* you essentially set the preference for new text frames.

FYI `Margins & Columns` is for *page guide columns* and does not alter text frames. If your *page* has 5 columns and you always want just one, then you'd change `Margins & Columns` with no file open.